# pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have restored a database using pg_restore. I found that data is restored but it throwed a few errors. What's the reason for these errors?

This is the command using for restoring

pg_restore -U postgres -d newdb08aug19 -j5   remote

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 7616;
 2606 36663585 FK CONSTRAINT card_history_cashcard_id_fk unify37
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "public.voucher" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY finance.card_history
    ADD CONSTRAINT card_history_cashcard_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (cashcard_id) REFERENCES pu...
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 7614; 2606 36662489 FK CONSTRAINT card_history_coupon_id_fk unify37
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "public.cpn" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY finance.card_history
    ADD CONSTRAINT card_history_coupon_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (coupon_id) REFERENCES public...
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 7615; 2606 36663406 FK CONSTRAINT card_history_domno_fk unify37
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "public.ssgdom" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY finance.card_history
    ADD CONSTRAINT card_history_domno_fk FOREIGN KEY (domno) REFERENCES public.ssgdom(...
```

What's the reason for these kind of errors?

Comment: Are you sure there is no version mismatch between the dump and the running PostgreSQL ?

Comment: No there's no version mismatch. As @laurenz Albe below said, I have taken the dump of  a single schema from the database and few constraints are missed from other schemas. So, thats the reasons for these errors during restoring.

Answer (score 2):

You only dumped part of the database (probably using something like `-n finance`, which would only dump objects in that schema).

So the foreign key constraints that reference table that are *not* included in the dump will cause an error message when the dump is restored.

Everything except the constraints will be restored correctly.

Comment: Yeah Got it. Thanks for the info.